# How to avoid multiple database queries for Hibernate Projection?

Tags: java, hibernate, projection

I have two classes with a unidirectional many-to-one relationship. Querying for one of the classes based on criteria of the other with a projection generates extra queries (n+1). **With Hibernate, how can a projection query avoid n+1 queries?**

Here's my model:

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=PersonType.class, optional=false)
    private PersonType personType;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    /* other supporting code */
}

@Entity
public class PersonType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    /* other supporting code */
}
```

Here's my criteria query

```java
session.createCriteria(Person.class)
        .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%" + nameContains + "%"))
        .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("personType")))
        .list()
        ;
```

And here's the Hibernate log for running the criteria:

```
Hibernate: select distinct this_.personType_id as y0_ from Person this_ where this_.name like ?
Hibernate: select persontype0_.id as id1_0_, persontype0_.name as name1_0_ from PersonType persontype0_ where persontype0_.id=?
Hibernate: select persontype0_.id as id1_0_, persontype0_.name as name1_0_ from PersonType persontype0_ where persontype0_.id=?
```

Hibernate does a query to get the `PersonType` ids, and then a query for each `PersonType` individually. These roundtrips are an expensive part of a web site request, and I'd like to avoid them.

I have [published](https://github.com/burkemw3/hibernate-projection-nplusone) a full reproduction on github for anyone to experiment with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery can be used:

```java
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Person.class)
        .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%" + nameContains + "%"))
        .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("personType.id")))
        ;
return session.createCriteria(PersonType.class)
        .add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", subquery))
        .list()
        ;
```

Here's the generated query:

```
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_0_, this_.name as name1_0_ from PersonType this_ where this_.id in (select distinct this_.personType_id as y0_ from Person this_ where this_.name like ?)
```

The subquery reduces round trips, but still may not be the most efficient query to execute on the database.

Comment: I'd love to see a solution that doesn't use subqueries!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
_sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class)
                .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%" + nameContains + "%"))
                .createAlias("personType", "personType")
                .setProjection(
                        Projections.projectionList().add(
                                Projections.distinct(Projections
                                        .property("personType.id")), "id").add(Projections
                                                .property("personType.name"), "name"))
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(PersonType.class))
                .list();
```

PersonType must have public getters and setters and a public constructor

Comment: Thanks ¶ In this example, the `PersonType` class only has two properties. In real life, classes will have many more properties. Does the query have to include projections for all of the properties of the `PersonType` class? ¶ Assuming so, that is not a reasonable solution.